# PHP PDO - incremental for loop that fetches the next array row with each loop

Tags: php, pdo

I'm in the process of updating my old mysql database techniques to prepared pdo statements. I'm all good with while loops `while($row = $result->fetch())` however how would I do the following with PDO prepared statements?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=".$id;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$loop_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($row=0;$row<7 && $loop_count-->0;$row++)
{
    // Get next row
    $loop_row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo $loop_row['field'];
}
```

I've tried this but with no joy:

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ?");
$result->execute(array($id));
$loop_count = $result->rowCount();

for($row=0;$row<7 && $loop_count-->0;$row++)
{
    // Get next row
    $loop_row = $result->fetch();

    echo $loop_row['field'];
}
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: The reason for using a for loop instead of a while loop is the ability to paginate the results, otherwise I would just put LIMIT 7 on the end of the SQL query.

Comment: When doing a select statement `rowCount` might not work for some databases.

Comment: If you only want 7 records why not do a limit 7? Then fetch the rows and output the values you want.

Comment: pagination of 7 per page

Comment: The issue is that you build your code expecting:  1) a fixed number of items per page and 2) that it is always has that many entries. However, if in your `for loop` the 'loop termination test' included a _`and  more data rows`_ test then your code would require minor changes and work correctly.

Comment: @RyanVincent could you give a code example in an answer so I can give that a try? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To properly count rows with PDO you have to do this -

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ?");
$result->execute(array($id));    
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $rows[0];
```

But you would be better off using `LIMIT` in your query if all you want to do is get a static number of results.

In addition you're making your loop overly complex, there is no need to test for a range in the `for` condition just set the static number *unless* you're doing something weird, like possibly pagination.

Comment: yep, pagination is the aim, hence the <7 bit in the loop = 7 per page. thus a limit won't work

Comment: Using `LIMIT` with an offset would still be preferable here.

Comment: the mysql manual says `[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]` this means that you can have a specified offset for your limit (example i'd use `LIMIT 7 OFFSET 7*$numpage` of course parametrized into a prepared statement.)

Comment: @STTLCU can you put that into the example I gave for me to give it a go? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ?");
$result->execute(array($id));
$loop_rows = $result->fetchAll();
$loop_count = count($loop_rows);

for($row=0;$row<7 && $loop_count-->0;$row++)
{
    // Get next row
    echo $loop_rows[$row]['field'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As requested by the OP, here's an example of PDO prepared statements using LIMIT and OFFSET for pagination purposes. Please note i prefer to use bindValue() rather than passing parameters to execute(), but this is personal preference.

```
$pagesize = 7; //put this into a configuration file
$pagenumber = 3; // NOTE: ZERO BASED. First page is nr. 0. 
                 //You get this from the $_REQUEST (aka: GET or POST)
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
                          FROM table 
                          WHERE id= :id 
                          LIMIT :pagesize 
                          OFFSET :offset");
$result->bindValue(':id', $id);
$result->bindValue(':pagesize', $pagesize);
$result->bindValue(':offset', $pagesize * $pagenumber);
$result->execute();    
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This gives you the complete resultset of rows, limited to your required page. You need another query to calculate the total number of rows, of course.

Answer (score -1):

What you could try is:

```
    //Get your page number for example 2
    $pagenum = 2;

    //Calculate the offset
    $offset = 7 * $pagenum; 

    //Create array     
    $data = array();

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ? LIMIT 7 OFFSET ?");
    $result->bind_param("ii", $id,$offset);
    $result->execute();

    $resultSet = $result->get_result();
    while ($item = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $data[] = $item;
    }

    $result->close();

    //echo resultSet you want
    var_dump($data);
```

Comment: The OP is trying to convert to `PDO` rather than `mysqli` statements.